# libxml2 : xmlFreeTextReader crashes

Tags: libxml2

I am using libxml2 (libxml2-2.7.8)
I get crash when I call xmlFreeTextReader after the XMl file is processed.
I do not have a clue as in why is it happening :

Following is the code that I am using:

```
int parseDevDescMessage(char *buffer, DMXDevice *dmxLocal)
{
  //xmlDocPtr xmlDocPointer;
  xmlTextReaderPtr xmlTextPointer;
  int           errorCode=0;
  const xmlChar *name, *value;
  char          *xmlBuffer;
  xmlNode       *rootElement = NULL;
  xmlNode       *currentNode = NULL;

  devServices   *devServicesLocal=NULL;
  devServices   *devServicesLocalAdd=NULL;

  /*
   * This initialize the library and check potential ABI mismatches
   * between the version it was compiled for and the actual shared
   * library used.
   */
  LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

  xmlBuffer = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
  strcpy(xmlBuffer, buffer, strlen(buffer));
  /*I am doing this string copy because the variable buffer is referred in the calling function. I am assuming that xmlFreeTextReader is freeing the buffer also

  xmlTextPointer = xmlReaderForMemory(xmlBuffer, strlen(xmlBuffer), "somthing.xml", NULL, 0);
  if(xmlTextPointer == NULL)
  {
    #ifdef CTL_MSG_PARSER_DEBUG_NEW
      printf("parseDevDescMessage : ERROR WHITE CREATING XML DOC FROM MEM\n");
    #endif
    errorCode = -1;
    goto error;
  }

  errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);  
  while(errorCode == 1)
  {
    if( ( (strcmp(xmlTextReaderConstName(xmlTextPointer),"serviceList")) == 0 ) &&
        ( (xmlTextReaderNodeType(xmlTextPointer)) == 1)
 )
    {
      errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
      while(errorCode == 1)
      {
        if( ( (strcmp(xmlTextReaderConstName(xmlTextPointer),"service")) == 0) &&
            ( (xmlTextReaderNodeType(xmlTextPointer)) == 1)
          )
        {
          devServicesLocal =  dmxLocal->deviceServices;

          if(!devServicesLocal)
          {
            devServicesLocal = (devServices *)malloc(sizeof(devServices));
            memset(devServicesLocal, 0, sizeof(devServices));
            dmxLocal->deviceServices = devServicesLocal;
            //devServicesLocalAdd      = devServicesLocal;
          }
          else
          {
            while(devServicesLocal->nextService)
            {
              devServicesLocal = devServicesLocal->nextService;
            }
            devServicesLocal->nextService = (devServices *)malloc(sizeof(devServices));
            memset(devServicesLocal->nextService, 0, sizeof(devServices));
            devServicesLocal = devServicesLocal->nextService;
          }
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);

          value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(xmlTextPointer);
          devServicesLocal->serviceType = (char *)malloc(strlen(value));
          strcpy(devServicesLocal->serviceType, value);


          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);

          value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(xmlTextPointer);
          devServicesLocal->serviceId = (char *)malloc(strlen(value));
          strcpy(devServicesLocal->serviceId, value);

          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);

          value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(xmlTextPointer);
          devServicesLocal->SCPDURL = (char *)malloc(strlen(value));
          strcpy(devServicesLocal->SCPDURL, value);


          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);

          value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(xmlTextPointer);
          devServicesLocal->eventSubURL  = (char *)malloc(strlen(value));
          strcpy(devServicesLocal->eventSubURL, value);


          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);

          value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(xmlTextPointer);
          devServicesLocal->controlURL  = (char *)malloc(strlen(value));
          strcpy(devServicesLocal->controlURL, value);

        }
        else
        {
          errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      errorCode = xmlTextReaderRead(xmlTextPointer);
    }
  }
  error:
  xmlMemoryDump();
  **xmlFreeTextReader(xmlTextPointer);**
  xmlCleanupParser();  
  return errorCode;
}
```

Can some one please explain why is this code crashing when xmlFreeTextReader(xmlTextPointer) is called

Answer (score 0):

I used VALGRIND and found a number of memory issues. I fixed one by one all the memory related issues and in the end this crash vanished.
Might be at some place because of the corruption this memory was held on because of which when this was released it was crashing.

Thanks,

-Sun